# warning : will never be excuted

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I updated an old Swift 1 app to Swift 2 using Xcode 7 and I'm getting a few warnings that were not there before I updated.

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

    // SWIFT 2 update
    state = .OptionsVisible
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}
```

That function is giving me 2 warnings that both the state and the super lines will not be executed, but I'm not sure why? I figured something changed between Swift 1 and 2, but I'm not really sure what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`fatalError` is now flagged as `@noreturn`, so the compiler can tell that nothing after that will be executed.

Comment: it's getting called in my app which is causing the app to stop, but I have no idea why. It worked fine before I updated to iOS 9 / XC7. I also getting this: check inputsfatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:

Comment: Why you're hitting this particular line of code is a completely different question from why are you seeing the compiler warning.  One which you don't provide enough information to hazard a guess at.  I'd suggest opening a new question with more details.